# why does Kibana forward the url to `/spaces/enter`?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kibana

I have a kibana running inside docker container in k8s. And I put a nginx as sidecar to forward all traffic to kibana based on path.

Below is my nginx configuration. It works fine for elasticsearch. But when I open `/kibana/` in browser, it redirects to `/spaces/enter` and shows `404 Not Found`.

In kibana container log I can see a 302 forward log:

`{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2021-02-24T05:50:32Z","tags":[],"pid":7,"method":"get","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/","method":"get","headers":{"connection":"Keep-Alive","proxy-connection":"Keep-Alive","host":"kibana-entrypoint:5601","x-forwarded-for":"49.255.115.150","x-forwarded-proto":"http","x-forwarded-port":"80","x-amzn-trace-id":"Root=1-6035e928-603d67da7eff4225005fdbfc","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"},"remoteAddress":"192.168.1.41","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"},"res":{"statusCode":302,"responseTime":7,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET / 302 7ms - 9.0B"}`

```
user nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
      worker_connections  10240;
    }
    http {
      server {
          listen       8080;
          server_name  localhost;
          location /es/ {
            proxy_pass  http://sample-es-entrypoint:9200/;
          }
          location /health {
            proxy_pass  http://sample-es-entrypoint:9200/_cluster/health;
          }
          location /kibana/ {
            proxy_pass  http://kibana-entrypoint:5601/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
            proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
          }
      }
    }
```

The question is why kibana forward the request?

Answer (score 2):

[`elastic/kibana` PR 66098](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/66098) mentions that the `/spaces/enter` view is used by the space selector UIs to send users to the appropriate default route.

And  [PR 44678](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/44678) explains the origin of the notion of space:

> This deprecates the `server.defaultRoute` from `kibana.yml` setting (#46787) in favor of an **Advanced Setting controllable through the UI**.
> By making this an advanced setting, it inherently becomes space-aware, so users can specify a custom default route per space.
>
> #### Transition
>
> If `server.defaultRoute` is specified in `kibana.yml`, it will be mapped to the `uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute` setting.
> This setting tells the UI Settings Service that the defaultRoute setting is locked, and cannot be edited via the UI.
> From a migration perspective, this is functionally equivalent for users upgrading in a minor release: the setting is only controllable via the `yml` file.
>
> #### Functionality
>
> Users who wish to take advantage of the space-aware routes simply need to remove the `server.defaultRoute` setting from their `yml` file, if set.
> If unset, the advanced setting defaults to `/app/kibana`, which was the previous default value for `server.defaultRoute`.

So in your case, check the  `kibana.yml` used by your Kibana Docker image: try and remove `server.defaultRoute` if set.